# What is the best practice for serializing C# immutable structs?

Tags: c#, serialization, attributes, readonly

I usually make my structs read-only. However, serialization libraries (e.g. `DataContractSerializer`) expect the serialized fields or attributes to be read/write.

So my options I believe are:

- Make my fields writable just to appease serializers
- Create proxy objects for the purpose of serialization
- Auto-generate proxies using reflection
- Auto-generate serialization/deserialization functions by trying to guess an
  appropriate constructor using heuristics or an attribute.

What do people normally do in this situation?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `DataContractSerializer` rather than say JSON.NET?

Comment: @mjwills Can JSON.NET deserialize into an immutable struct?

Comment: @MattArnold Looks like it - https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1218 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataContractSerializer is able to serialize read-only fields if you initialize it like this

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(
       typeof(ToSerialize),
       new DataContractSerializerSettings() 
       { 
          SerializeReadOnlyTypes =  true
       });
```

But this will only work one-way if you want to deserialize a class with a property that has only a getter. So you can serialize, but not deserialize something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public struct ToSerialize
{
  public ToSerialize(string a)
  {
    PropertyToSerialize = "a";
  }

  [DataMember]
  public string PropertyToSerialize { get; }
}
```

So either you add a private set to your property, or add a backing field and mark it with [DataMember] attribute.

```
[DataContract]
public struct ToSerialize
{
  public ToSerialize(string a)
  {
    backingField = "a";
  }

  public string PropertyToSerialize => backingField;

  [DataMember]
  string backingField;
}
```

By using private setters you are making it hard to change the state of the object (you can probably do it using reflection). So if there are no methods changing the fields in your struct and all properties have private setters, your struct is technically immutable. I would go for a private setter in your case, it is more readable and takes less amount of effort than playing with reflection.